# Subscriptions google market billing api for android

Tags: android

In my android app internaly useing some transactions in  that purpose i want use      **Subscriptions Google market billing **.

i googled found some sites for In-app billing and Subscriptions ,now want used Subscriptions based api but not found any code related this api.i found in-app billing code only.
please send Subscriptions based code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one specific API. It is an extension of in-app billing with a new parameter and a couple of modifications in the APIs. For example, in the RequestPurchase call in BillingService.java, the item type now needs to be 'subs'. You really need to read the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

as well as download the 'Google play billing Rev 2' from the 'Extras' from the SDK manager as that's a sample app that does subscriptions. The entire code base for it is too big to just give you but the sample app is a good start. I suspect with such a vague question, you're not going to get more details.